# Angular ng-style does not apply on FontAwesome icons

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-style

I am simply tyring to change the color of the a fa-square from fontAwseome dynamically using angular and NG-Style. Here is how:

```
<p><i class="fa fa-square blue" ng-style="{'color': portfolio_risk.values.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[0]}"></i> {{portfolio_risk.values.data.labels[0]}} </p>
```

The style seems to just not be applied, cause in the browse when i inspect the element color is still set by the class 'blue', I have also tried to get rid of this class but nothing changes.

Comment: which version? V5 or V4

Comment: the version on npm 1.6.10

Comment: Whats the value you are getting in `portfolio_risk.values.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[0]` ?

Comment: This is the value i get if i print it in html: #FF00000

Comment: `#FF00000` is not a valid color should be `#FF0000`

Comment: Just changed it same problem.

Comment: I have even just tried: ng-style="{'color': '#FF0000'}" still no effect

Comment: is your class `blue` has **!important** ? if yes removing it might solve your issue

Comment: nope it doesn't, its the standard FontAwesome class, I have tried to put the "!important" in the ngstyle as well no success

Comment: Do you have any method that color will change, if yes could you post it here also

Comment: No no other method.